# The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack .Xml.XmlFile" task was not found

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am new in MSbuild when i tried to build the project using Command Prompt I got the below error

> error MSB4036: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile" task was not
>   found. Check the following:
>
> ```
>  1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class.
>  2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.
>  3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As seeing your Error it clearly points out that your are using .net Framework version **4.0.30319** therefore You can't run **.NET 4.0 assemblies** with the **3.5 version** of the .NET tools.

A detailed discussion can be found here :

https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack/issues/1